# How to sum a row of values from a text file using Python

Tags: python

I have rows of values in a text file which looks like this:

```
2,3,4,2
4,5,6,3
2,3,4,1
```

I want to be able to sum them in rows:

Eg,

```
row1 = 11
row2 = 18
row3 = 10
```

I have tried to add all the lines in a multi dimensional array, however I am having difficulties. I have tried the codes below:

```
allVotes=[]
fo=open('Votes.txt','r')

for line in fo:
  line=line.strip()
  parts=line.split(',')
  eachLine=int(line)
  allVotes.append(eachLine)
print(allVotes)
```

However, each line is not an integer. Any other ways to solve this?

Comment: After `parts=line.split(',')`, you need to `sum(map(int, parts))` to get the sum of current ints in the line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get it into a 2-D array try this

```
all_values = []
with open('Votes.txt', 'rt') as file:
    for line in file:
        line = list(map(int, string.split(",")))
        all_values.append(line)
```

Or you could do something like this to get the sum of each line in a 1d array.

```
def get_results(filename):

    def sum_line(line):
        return sum(map(int, line.split(",")))

    with open(filename, 'rt') as file:
        return [sum_line(line) for line in file]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not convert a list of strings to list of integers with int() call on that list, you need to convert each value separately since [int()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) function accepts strings only.

To do that you can use [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) or [map function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map):

```
# List comprehension
eachLine = [int(s) for s in line]

# using map function
eachLine = list(map(int, line))
```

You can call [sum()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) on these lists to get the sums. So, in your case results can be achieved by the following code:

```
fo=open('Votes.txt','r')

for line in fo:
    vote_sums = sum([int(s) for s in line.strip().split(',')])
    print(vote_sums)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
fo=open('rank.txt','r')
for line in fo:
    l=list(map(int,line.split(",")))
    sm=sum(l[0:len(l)])
    print (sm)
```

Answer (score 0):

`sum(map(lambda x: int(x), raw_input().split(',')))`

Answer (score 0):

Using **pandas** we can do this in a single-row operation.

```
s = u"""2,3,4,2
4,5,6,3
2,3,4,1"""

import io
import pandas as pd

l = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s),header=None).sum(axis=1).tolist()
#l = pd.read_csv("path/to/file.csv",header=None).sum(axis=1).tolist()
```

l returns:

```
[11, 18, 10]
```

With pandas we can also export to dictionaries:

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s),header=None).sum(axis=1)
df.index = ("row {}".format(i+1) for i in range(len(df)))
d = df.to_dict()
```

d returns

```
{'row 1': 11, 'row 2': 18, 'row 3': 10}
```